# Htaccess rewrite URL with parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I've been trying to make a htaccess rewrite for this URL:
https://www.test.com/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=abcd12345&login=username
to
https://www.test.com/reset-password/?action=rp&key=abcd12345&login=username

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^reset-password/?rp=([a-z]+)&key=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)&login=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ wp-login.php?action=$1&key=$2&login=$3 [L,R=302]
```

It doesn't work, can anyone shed some light?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

QueryString is not part of match in rule's pattern, you need to match against `%{QUERY_STRING}` .

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^rp=([a-z]+)&key=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)&login=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$
RewriteRule ^reset-password/ wp-login.php?action=%1&key=%2&login=%3 [L,R=302]
```